# Fetching data from Firebase using Axios in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

[image]

I am getting TypeError: response.forEach is not a function and can't fetch the data.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't troubleshoot images here.

Comment: You probably want to wrap that loop in a check to see that `response` contains something iterable. That error doesn't say anything about the fetch failing, though, just that it doesn't contain what your code expects.

Comment: The REST API returns a JSON object and not a DataSnapshot like the SDK iirc.

Comment: You should show a log of what `response` is bringing back.